# C++ ShellExecute specifically not opening LNK files

Tags: c++, winapi, shellexecute

-Windows 7 64-bit
-Visual Studio 2013 (v120)
-Unicode Enabled
-Target Build- Debug 32-bit

I would like to build a launcher (for personal use) however I can't get ShellExecute to work with all file types or paths, specifically shortcuts (LNK). I've researched and tried the following in many combinations...
-I'm using escape sequences
-I'm adding the file extension (and tried without)
-I've included Windows.h
-Printed directory FindFirstFile / FindNextFile to explicitly ensure the path has no typos
-Tried using both a literal and variable as file path argument
-Tried running VS with admin privileges
-Tried ShellExecute, ShellExecuteA, ShellExecuteEx, and System (with appropriate character sets)
-Tried NULL, "runas" and, "open" for the verb
-Launches fine from Command Line or explorer using same path
-Tried using %USERPROFILE% macro instead of user name (returns 2)
-Seems to work with EXE and URLs
-Does not seem to work with any LNK across any path including C:\ directly

Suspected issue
-32bit/64bit discrepancy
-UAC / Privelages
-Character set
-File extension
-Anti virus interference (though AV isn't alerting me of any issues) and I've tested while silencing my AV

Here is one of the simplest programs I've tried...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <atlstr.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);

    // Variables below for testing as path argument
    // Paths that end with LNK are the only ones that I can't get to launch
    CStringW link("C:\\Users\\Home\\Documents\\Art\\blender.lnk"); // Doesn't work
    CStringW target("C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\blender.exe"); // Launches software as expected
    CStringW url("https://stackoverflow.com"); // Launches browser with URL as expected

    int error = reinterpret_cast<int>(ShellExecute(
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        L"C:\\Users\\Home\\Documents\\Art\\blender.lnk", // Using literal with LNK extension also does not work
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        SW_SHOWDEFAULT
        ));


    // EVEN SYSTEM CAN NOT FIND THE PATH!!!
    // system("C:\\Users\\Home\\Documents\\Art\\blender.lnk");

    std::cout << error << std::endl; // Returns 3 "The specified path was not found.".

    // Free COM
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify in the *question*: Is your program compiled for 32-bit or 64-bit? Is the target of the link `C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\blender.exe`? There are a few unused variables in the code sample, which should be removed (they are just confusing).

Comment: What happens if you put a `Sleep(6666);` after ShellExecute?

Comment: Updated OP. The blender shortcut was indeed created from the executable path BUT as I said before I have not been able to get ANY .lnk files to launch with ShellExecute. So far, all .exe and other extensions have worked. I'm not sure why I was requested to use Sleep() but I tried with the suggested time and it slept and returned 3 like before.

Comment: Are you sure it fails for any LNK file? I can repro only for LNK files that point to a path under `C:\Program Files`, but LNK files pointing to `C:\Program Files (x86)` do work, which clearly indicates a 32/64-bit issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check that your .lnk file is in the path.

Then (and the most probable cause of your problem) check that your .lnk filename is created correctly. To make sure it is not like "blender.lnk.lnk"(I can reproduce your issue if I have set as this).

You can also try to parse the path of the link file manually by yourself.
Here is the sample:

```
void ShortcutToRealpath(LPWSTR pszString, LPSTR pdzString)
{
    IShellLink   *pShellLink;
    HRESULT hRes;

    ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    hRes = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (void **)&pShellLink);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
    {
        IPersistFile   *ppf;
        hRes = pShellLink->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (void **)&ppf);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
        {
            hRes = ppf->Load(pszString, TRUE);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
            {
                pShellLink->GetPath(pdzString, MAX_PATH, NULL, 0);
            }
            ppf->Release();
        }
        pShellLink->Release();
    }
    ::CoUninitialize();
}
```

When I build as x86 Platform, the path will be parsed like:
[image]
That's the reason your program can't find the path.

And if I select x64:
[image]

Put your target file to the corresponding file.

EDIT:

After I test it with the MS tool [Procmom.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), I have found something others, if run as 32-bit, it will show :
[image]

The key value is `C:\Program Files (x86)` and if we run it as 64-bit, the key is reference to "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir" the key value is `C:\Program Files`. After I check the registry:
[image]
[image]
It seems that `C:\Program Files` is not visible by default to the 32-bit registry(I am not sure about the specific reason).
If you change the key `ProgramFilesDir` to `C:\Program Files` in 32-bit registry, the issue will be fixed.

Comment: I'm certain the path is correct. I just copy/pasted the path from Visual Studio to the Command Prompt (removed ONLY the escape slashes) and it launched the file as expected. I previously read the path with a function and it was also shown as expected.

Comment: @Jeremiah T And, what about the filename, use cmd go into the path of .lnk file, then dir to check the filename if it is "blender.lnk.lnk". And what's the return value `hRes` of `ppf->Load(pszString, TRUE);`

Comment: hi,@Jeremiah T  `IShellLink.GetPath` can parse the full path of the file, and the result depends on the platform you compile. So that's the reason you have the wrong path, program has gone to the wrong folder. And I have updated it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see what your function was getting at before. You and zett42 have shown me the problem. It was just a coincidence that ALL the shortcuts I tested were pointing at x64 executables. I even stated in the OP that it might have to do with 32/64-bit discrepancy but abandoned that suspicion too soon I suppose. However, I still need a solution. What's the best way to resolve a shortcut's target path at run-time regardless of 32/64 build?

Comment: Finally, I find the root cause and a workaround, see my edit in answer.